how to implement coordination layout with transparent status bar with search bar
i am working in android studio and creating this layout but i do not able to create it
and the layout is overlapping the status bar.
this is the layout:
enter image description here
this is the code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">

        <!-- Material Toolbar for the Top Action Bar -->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/header">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:text="Delivery"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <!-- Include layout for throwable items -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/header">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/search_icon"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="Search here"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- RecyclerView for the main content -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

theme:
   <style name="Theme.Flutter" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>

for full screen:
  private void enableEdgeToEdge(Window window) {
        // Makes the content go edge-to-edge
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false);

        // Control the appearance of the system bars
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat controller = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.getDecorView());

        // Optional: Set light status bar so the text and icons appear in dark color
        controller.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);

        // Optional: Set light navigation bar so the icons appear in dark color
        controller.setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(true);

    }

i want the same transition effect and design
note: the status bar should transparent and layout should be in full screen
